# How to sum certain data from a SQL query and subtract the sum of other data?

Tags: sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT amount, conamt, id, spended, cspended
FROM coins 
WHERE id = 'D00' AND idntf IN ('DFA0D02A', ...);
```

If `spended=0` then this is the arrival of the goods, if `spended=1` then this is the dispatch. How can I get the total amount where `spended=0` minus the total amount where `spended=1`.
sum(amount(spended=0))-sum(amount(spended=1))

[image]

Now I get the amount `SUM(amount)` by grouping through:

```
GROUP BY amount, conamt
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

But there are mistakes if the same amount of goods arrived in one batch on the same day.

Comment: `sum(case when spended = 0 then amount else - amount end)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, idntf,
NetAmount= sum(case when spended = 0 then amount else -1*amount end)
from coins
WHERE id = 'D00' AND idntf IN ('DFA0D02A') --change here as you like
group by id, idntf
```

Comment: Note that this is a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP (and the rest of us) which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN spended = 0 THEN amount) END as arrival,
     SUM(CASE WHEN spended = 1 THEN amount) END as dispatch
  from coins 
)
SELECT arrival - dispatch FROM CTE
```

Use a `CASE` statement to see per row what the condition is, and add that to the `SUM()`. You can remove the CTE and do it all in one statement if you wish.

Comment: ....
from coins 
WHERE id = 'D00' AND idntf IN ('DFA0D02A', ...);
)
SELECT arrival - dispatch FROM CTE

Maybe I did something wrong but it gives me a syntax error

Comment: @YuliyaM You're using ... inside the IN statement this is not allowed. You either specifiy integers or a string inside quotation marks. Can you post the entire query you are trying to run?